# how do I escape a comma?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikz picture and at some point I draw the following node:

```
\node[thick,
      scale=0.5,
      minimum size=1.3cm,
      fill=red,
      circle,
      draw,
      fill opacity=0.3,
      label=right:$= (0 1 0 1 0 \ldots)$
      ] (the) at (6.2, 1.5) { };
```

The thing is that I want to separate the 0 1 0 1, etc with commas. I can't do that, because I think TikZ thinks it separates the next parameter in the square brackets. How can I escape the comma?

Comment: Put braces around the label.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

By eating healthy or using braces around shady characters.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[thick,
      scale=0.5,
      minimum size=1.3cm,
      fill=red,
      circle,
      draw,
      fill opacity=0.3,
      label=right:{$= (0,1,0,1,0,\ldots)$}
      ] (the) at (6.2, 1.5) { };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the food tip.